# Not able to verify SMIME messages signature signed with SHA256WITHRSA in Bouncy castle in java

Tags: bouncycastle, smime

One of our partner is sending signed SMIME messages to us using NOSPAMPROXY. Everything works fine except the one using SHA256WITHRSA . Bouncy castle is saying that the signature verification failed. Please see the code segment below,

```
public static boolean verifySignature(SMIMESigned s, X509Certificate myCert) throws Exception {
        SignerInformationStore signers = s.getSignerInfos();
        Collection c = signers.getSigners();
        for (Iterator it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            try {
                SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
                final SignerInformationVerifier verifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).build(
                    myCert);
                if (signer.verify(verifier)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (CMSException ex) {
                Tracer.debug(ex);
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

myCert is the certificate we are giving for verify. Any help is appreciated .

Comment: BC certainly should be able to handle sha256-RSA, and does for me. To be clear, it's returning false and not throwing an exception? If so I would first check you're using/selecting the correct cert (is it from the message or elsewhere?) and then crosscheck with openssl.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, BC is not throwing any exception, it is giving false , which means the certificate is not matching . but the thing is Openssl is able to verify this signature with the same certificate.

Comment: As I said are you sure your code is selecting the correct cert to verify with? OpenSSL selects automatically (by signer id). If so, can you take or create an example with nonsensitive data and add to your Q?

Comment: Hi, I got the solution for the same,
:Issues you can find here:http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BJA-587, http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BJA-626
Example for reference:https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pkix/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/cms/test/NewSignedDataTest.java